# Kodi replaced Unity after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: unity, kodi, 17.10

Has anyone encountered a scenario where Kodi became the desktop environment post Ubuntu 17.10 installation?

I had Kodi installed and forgotten unused on my Ubuntu 17.04 pre-upgrade. I heard Ubuntu is leaving Unity behind in 17.10, but had not expected Kodi to take ownership as desktop env instead.

Any tip on how to resolve this situation cleanly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Look for the little gear next to the "Sign In" button. You should see a list with Ubuntu as one of the options. Select that before you click "Sign In".

You need to select the login option "Ubuntu on Xorg".

See: [How to Switch to Xorg from Wayland in Ubuntu 17.10](https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/)

Kodi for Ubuntu doesn't seem to work with Wayland just yet.

{Edit on Thursday Nov 2} : Kodi now works with Wayland on Ubuntu after a system update. You no longer need to use the login option "Ubuntu on Xorg" as the default "Ubuntu" login (which uses Wayland) now works.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the little gear next to the "Sign In" button.  You should see a list with Ubuntu as one of the options.  Select that before you click "Sign In".